# Sections with multiple key path Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

i want to split a core data request with multiple sectionNameKeyPath. let me give a example: i have events in data base (Attributes: title, hour, profile). i want to show to user events separated in sections by hour and profile. only find how to do using only one attribute (using NSFetchedResultsController), hour or profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make it, inspired by this: http://blog.adambardon.com/tableview-with-many-sections-and-items-from-array/

In "sortedSections" i just put a concatenated string with those two attributes, and don't used this on the title (put informations directly from the data array objects).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot section by two attributes (it's nonsensical, see below). You can section by attribute with the objects in each sections sorted by the other attributes. (Simply add a second sort key.)

To section "by two attributes" does not make any sense. You would get completely unusable data like

```
11:25 - John
11:30 - Bob
11:30 - John
11:32 - John
11:33 - Bill
```

or

```
Bill - 11:33
Bob  - 11:30
John - 11:25
John - 11:30
John - 11:32
```

*Applied Dadaism.*

Answer (score 0):

If you pass multiple sort descriptors to the fetch request, you'll get something close to what I think you're describing.

To get Mundi's example (sort by Name first, then by Time), you'd pass an array of two sort descriptors:

```
Bill - 11:33
Bob  - 11:30
John - 11:25
John - 11:30
John - 11:32
```

Then pass the Name property as your section name keypath. That will give you something like

```
Bill
    Bill - 11:33
Bob
    Bob  - 11:30
John
    John - 11:25
    John - 11:30
    John - 11:32
```